# How to read xcb_input_fp3232_t and xcb_input_fp1616_t

Tags: xlib, xcb, xinput

I have implemented a xinput2 listener to my window with the following code:

```
...
else if(eID == XCB_GE_GENERIC){ // Generic events = XINPUT
        auto* gev = (xcb_ge_generic_event_t*)event;

        if(gev->extension != extensionXInput->major_opcode){
            continue;
        }

        auto inputEvent = gev->event_type;
        if(inputEvent == XCB_INPUT_MOTION){
            auto *ev = (xcb_input_motion_event_t *)event;
            std::cout << ev->event_x << " - " << ev->event_y << std::endl;
            //BUTTON_ON_MOTION(ev);
        }
```

But when I read the event_x and event_y fields I get very high numbers.

How can I properly read these numbers?

Answer (score 1):

fp1616 means "fixed point 16.16". This means that the first 16 bits represent the integer part of the number and the second 16 bits represent the fractional part.

See e.g. [Fixed point vs Floating point number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524838/fixed-point-vs-floating-point-number) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

For example, the number `1.0` is represented as `1 << 16`. The number `1.5` is `1.5 * (1 << 16)` which is equivalent to `3 << 15`.

Your calculation is "almost correct". You are using `0xffff` as the factor, but the correct number is `0x10000`. This should result in a tiny, tiny difference.

Answer (score 0):

While I have no idea how this works internally, and what the gobble returned represents, the following code will convert them to readable numbers.

```
    double fp3232val(xcb_input_fp3232_t* val)
    {
        return val->integral + val->frac / (double)UINT_MAX;
    }
    
    double fp1616val(xcb_input_fp1616_t val)
    {
        return val / (double)UINT16_MAX;
    }
```