# Why java converts double to exponential form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, exponential

I have a problem. In my jsp page I have a textfield which accepts monetary value. When I enter a value such as `66777764` it becomes `6.6777764E7` in my textfield whenever there is a validation error. I know this won't affect the value saved in the database but I think its misleading/confusing to the user. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's all in how you're formatting the `double`. Search for "[java format double](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+format+double)" and you'll get plenty of information. Also, **never** use `double` (or other floating point for monetary values.

Answer (score 9):

It seems you keep your number as `double` so `66777764` is actually `66.777764.0` and it displays what you got.

You can use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to format the display of the number as you wish, for example:

```
double d = 1.234567;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.print(df.format(d)); // will print 1.23
```

This will display the number with 2 digits after the point (`66777764.00`), there are many options for the format, check the documentation for info.

Comment: The BigDecimal answers are still good recommendations about monetary.

Answer (score 7):

follow [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(inputVal);
System.out.println(bd);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to keep the monetary value.

```
double d = 66777764d;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
System.out.println(bd);
```

Read [the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6320316/1535679) to find out why you should use BigDecimal.

Comment: And I'd like to add: Never ever use floating point number, i.e. double or float in Java, to hold monetary values. You'll get in trouble.