# Textbox allows only decimal values and numbers in gwt

Tags: gwt

I am using validation in GWT. I am having textbox. In that field it accepts only whole numbers and decimal values not other than special characters . I used  regex pattern "[0-9*]" but it does not accept decimal values. Can you give me one solution

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation

Answer (score 2):

You have to subclass textBox and handle conversion in your subclass. I.e. create some "BigDecimalBox".
Then use this in the object which is going to be validated.

```
private static final String MIN_VALUE = "0.00";
private static final String MAX_VALUE = "99999.99";
@DecimalMax(value = MAX_VALUE)
@DecimalMin(value = MIN_VALUE)
private BigDecimal mortgage;
```

Avoid using double for decimal values. It's a [known Java trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6320316/1722236) and a no-no if you are an enterprise developper! IMO GWT should provide a BigDecimalBox by default.

Answer (score 1):

GWT has tree specific TextBox for input number :
[IntegerBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/IntegerBox.html), [LongBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/LongBox.html) and [DoubleBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DoubleBox.html).

Theses textbox will validate the format of the input text and return the Integer, Long or Double Value.

Comment: It is not wise to use double for decimal values. Check this post for details http://stackoverflow.com/a/6320316/1722236.

Comment: Good point @otonglet. I missed out this part. In this case I think it may be better to extend `ValueBox<BigDecimal>` instead of plain `TextBox` as it is done for DoubleBox.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I had the same question.

I found GWT Bootstrap's BigDecimalBox in package com.github.gwtbootstrap.client.ui. It provides a BigDecimalRenderer (for display) and a BigDecimalParser (for parsing).

https://gwtbootstrap.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the key pressed by the user and prevent processing of invalid keys. I've done this by subclassing IntegerBox and using a KeyDownHandler to verify appropriate cases. Here is the full class.

```
public class IntegerTextBox extends IntegerBox {

public IntegerTextBox() {
    super();
}

public void initialize() {

    addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
        public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
            int keyCode = event.getNativeKeyCode();

            if (event.isAnyModifierKeyDown())
                cancelKey();

            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyCodes.KEY_LEFT:
                case KeyCodes.KEY_RIGHT:
                case KeyCodes.KEY_DELETE:
                case KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE:
                case KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER:
                case KeyCodes.KEY_ESCAPE:
                case KeyCodes.KEY_TAB:
                    return;
            }

            String parsedInput = parseNumberKey(keyCode);
            if (parsedInput.length() > 0) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                cancelKey();
            }

        }
    });
}

/**
 * Varifies that the key pressed is either a number key or a numeric pad key. Converts numeric pad keys to the string
 * representation of their number values.
 *  
 * @param keyCode - the key code.
 * @return the key's number representation as a string.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("nls")
private String parseNumberKey(int keyCode) {
    String result = new String();

    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyCodes.KEY_ZERO:
    case KeyCodes.KEY_ONE:
    case KeyCodes.KEY_TWO:
    case KeyCodes.KEY_THREE:
    case KeyCodes.KEY_FOUR:
    case KeyCodes.KEY_FIVE:
    case KeyCodes.KEY_SIX:
    case KeyCodes.KEY_SEVEN:
    case KeyCodes.KEY_EIGHT:
    case KeyCodes.KEY_NINE:
        return result = String.valueOf((char) keyCode);            
    case KeyCodes.KEY_NUM_ZERO:
        return result = "0";
    case KeyCodes.KEY_NUM_ONE:
        return result = "1";
    case KeyCodes.KEY_NUM_TWO:
        return result = "2";
    case KeyCodes.KEY_NUM_THREE:
        return result = "3";
    case KeyCodes.KEY_NUM_FOUR:
        return result = "4";
    case KeyCodes.KEY_NUM_FIVE:
        return result = "5";
    case KeyCodes.KEY_NUM_SIX:
        return result = "6";
    case KeyCodes.KEY_NUM_SEVEN:
        return result = "7";
    case KeyCodes.KEY_NUM_EIGHT:
        return result = "8";
    case KeyCodes.KEY_NUM_NINE:
        return result = "9";
    }
    return result;
}

}
```