# How do I calculate numbers with If statement if more than one condition is met?

Tags: java, if-statement, addition, assignment-operator, assign

I have edited my code below with the changes I have made. Here is the output I am getting.

Please enter an item.imported bottle of perfume
Please enter the price for imported bottle of perfume: 47.50
Would you like to continue to add items? (Type Y) for Yes and (Type N) for No.n
Your cart contains the following at items with tax{imported box of chocolate=10.00, imported bottle of perfume=67.50}
67.50

The box of chocolate should be 10.50 and the imported bottle should be 54.65. I use the debug and saw that the total price variable I am using holds 10.50 but it looks like it changes back. Also, instead of reading the loop that has

```
 if (item.contains("imported") && item.contains("bottle"))
```

it reads

```
 else if (item.contains("imported"))
```

first. My full code is below.

```
public class SalesTax 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // Input items for shopping cart
    HashMap<String, String> cart = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> shoppingcart = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // Create a Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // variables
    char done;

    //boolean goods;
    double totalprice = 0.00;
    double taxprice;

    // Pick items for list.
    do 
    {  
        System.out.print("Please enter an item.");
        String item = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please enter the price for "+ item + ": ");
        String price = input.nextLine(); 

        double price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
        totalprice += price1; 

        //System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",totalprice));
        String price2 = String.valueOf(price1);
        cart.put(item, price2);

        //determine if item will have additional tax
        if (item.contains("music"))
        {
             price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
            taxprice = price1 * .10;

            totalprice = (totalprice + taxprice);

            //System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",totalprice));
            String newprice2 = String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", price1 * 1.10));
            shoppingcart.put(item,newprice2);
        }
        else if (item.contains("imported"))
        {
             price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
            taxprice = price1 * .05;

            totalprice = (totalprice + taxprice);

            //System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",totalprice));
            String newprice2 = String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", totalprice));
            shoppingcart.put(item,newprice2);
        }
        if (item.contains("imported") && item.contains("bottle"))
        {
             price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
            taxprice = price1 * (.05 + .10);

            totalprice = (totalprice + taxprice);

            //System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",totalprice));
            String newprice2 = String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", totalprice));
            shoppingcart.put(item,newprice2);
        }
        else if(item.contains("bottle"))
        {
             price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
            taxprice = price1 * .10;

            totalprice = (price1 + taxprice);

            //System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",totalprice));
            String newprice2 = String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", price1 * 1.10));
            shoppingcart.put(item,newprice2);
        }
        else 
        {
            shoppingcart.put(item, price);
        }


        System.out.print("Would you like to continue to add items? (Type Y) for Yes and (Type N) for No.");
        done = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
    } while(Character.toUpperCase(done) == 'Y');

   System.out.println("Your cart contains the following at items with tax" + shoppingcart); //+ String.format("%.2f", totalprice));
   System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",totalprice));
}
```

}

Comment: Using an `&&` operator!

Comment: Don't use `else if`.

Comment: Process each item separately, in  a loop.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow :D

Comment: As a side-bar: It is not a great idea to do arithmetic involving money using `double`, since floating point arithmetic is not exact. You should look into using `BigDecimal` instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320209/javawhy-should-we-use-bigdecimal-instead-of-double-in-the-real-world

Comment: If you use map that way you will replace items with the same name i.e. you can't buy the same item more than once but you still have to pay the full price.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `&&` operator.  It's called the ***logical AND operator***.

```
//if item contains both "imported" and "bottle"
if (item.contains("imported") && item.contains("bottle")){
    //code
}
```

[Read more about operators here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: It is called the **logical** and operator.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use any kinds of an `if` statement you pass a boolean variable to it. There are two logical operators in Java that take two booleans and output one boolean:

- && (logical AND)
- || (logical OR)

`b1 && b2` is `true` if `b1` and `b2` are `true` - otherwise it is `false`.

`b1 || b2` is `true` if `b1` or `b2` or both are `true` - otherwise it is `false`.

In your case if you want to execute the same block of code when `"music"` or `"bottle"` are contained in the input text, you would do something like this:

```
if(items.contains("music") || items.contains("bottle")) {
    //modify prices
}
```