# NaN, Java trouble

Tags: java, nan, double-precision

I am trying to divide two full double values (i.e. double variables with all the memory filled up with a high precision number). Moreover, the result of the operation will be allocated in a double variable.

When I do the process, this one returns me NaN.

I read in some place before that two full double values when multiplied or divided between themselves will result in a high memory value, one that cannot be allocated in a double variable.

Am I right?

How could I solve this trouble?

```
public class CoeficienteAngular {

    public static double coefAngularImpar(    int x/*Coeficiente 
    da longarina a qual se analiza*/,         double y/*Distância 
    entre as longarinas*/,                     double z/*Somatorio*/){

        double beta;
        double betaPrim;

        betaPrim = (double) x/y;
        beta = betaPrim/z;

        return beta;
    }

    public static double coefAngularPar(    int x/*Coeficiente 
    da longarina que se analiza*/,             double y/*Distância 
    entre as longarinas*/,                     double z/*Somatório*/){

        double numerador, denominador, fatorCorrecao;
        double beta;

        int moduloL = Math.abs(x);

        numerador = (double)(moduloL-1)+(double)(1/2);
        denominador = y*z;

        fatorCorrecao = 1;//Inicializando a variável
        if(x>=0){
            fatorCorrecao = 1;
        }else if(x<0){
            fatorCorrecao = -1;
        }

        beta = fatorCorrecao*(numerador/denominador);
        return beta;
    }

}
```

Comment: What? What do you mean by _all memory filled up with a high precision number_? Please give an example.

Comment: I mean with all the decimals places occupied. For example: 0,333333333333333. I believe that is the most amount of decimals places possible to be allocated by a double variable.

Comment: Again, give us an example. They can be occupied by 0s.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say.  Can you give an example with complete code?

Comment: [There are rules concerning floating-point division](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2), but unless you pinpoint where it is you're experiencing this, we couldn't tell you.  I'd say, if you're getting overflow, you may want to switch to `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: I tried to use BigDecimal. But BigDecimal is a final type object. I thank you so much, but there are so many nested classes. It is not worth to copy and paste all here.

Comment: Do you know that this `(double)(1/2)` will always be `0.0`? If not, then change it to `(1.0/2.0)` (without the cast).

Comment: Sincerely, I did not know. Thank you, Tom. I will correct it. But, if I do like you suggested won't "1/2" become "0"?

Comment: That is why I wrote `1.0/2.0` :). This is the division of two floating point values which returns `0.5`. `(double)(1/2)` instead divides as integer, returns `0` and casts that result to double => `0.0`. You could also write `1D/2D`. The `D` (`d` would also work) marks the number as a `double` value.

Comment: kkkkk. I did like you suggested and now i got "infinite"... I am completely lost now.

Comment: You will get `infinite` if the value of a `double` variable exceeds  the limit for `double` types. More information about that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html.

Comment: Firstly, there's no such thing as a "full" or "empty" `double`. A double _always_ takes 64 bits, of which 52 are _always_ precision bits. Whether those bits are 0s or 1s doesn't make them more or less "full," any more than "0001" is a shorter string than "1111". Secondly, if the result of floating-point arithmetic is larger than the floating point can hold (in your case, because the two terms are very large), then the result "overflows" to infinity, which is a special value meant for just such situations. It sounds like you should read a tutorial, which is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Thank you, @yshavit. In this case, how could I adjust the values in each variable to the result be able to be allocated in a double variable? Or never a multiplication between two double variables will be able to be allocated in a other double variable?

Comment: If the result of the multiplication might be bigger than what a double can hold (which is an [absurdly large number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE)), then yes, you'll need to do something else. Using `BigDecimal` is one option; another is to use a different unit, so that the same thing can be expressed in smaller numbers. For instance, if I could only count to 25,000, then I couldn't describe the circumference of the earth in feet (~131,480,000), but I could describe it in miles (24,901).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use doubles. To avoid precision loss, use `BigDecimal` instead ([see Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)). You can also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320209/javawhy-should-we-use-bigdecimal-instead-of-double-in-the-real-world) where people explained perfectly the reasons for using BigDecimal.