# showing complete value of double in java without scientific notation

Tags: java

```
double d = 5000000000000000000034534534d;
System.out.println(String.valueOf(d)); // prints 5.0E27
```

Now, I want to display complete number instead of scientific notation.

As a fix, I have added new Bigdecimal which works fine till 10-12 digits not for big numbers.

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(d).toString()) // prints 4999999999999999791559868416
```

which is not same as double value. Need a solution to print correct number as double till 25 digits.

Comment: `4999999999999999791559868416` ***is*** the real value of `d`.

Comment: If you just want to print it, save it as a String? :-)

Comment: but I want to display 5000000000000000000034534534

Comment: @Sunny that is not representable as a double - if you need precision use BigDecimal (or BigInteger if the number is an integer).

Comment: @Manu this value is calculated from lot of sources. I have added a simple variable here to reduce complexity while asking this question.

Comment: @assylias: I did not understand your comment. Why that is real value of `d`?

Comment: @Parth that number is very large and can't be represented exactly as a double - so it is "rounded" to the closest integer that can.

Answer (score 1):

Your double value contains way too many significant digits and it can't be stored into a double.

You need to use a BigDecimal.

Please have a look to this SO answer about the reason [Why should we use BigDecimal instead of Double in the real world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320209/javawhy-should-we-use-bigdecimal-instead-of-double-in-the-real-world)