# Want to format numbers greater than 20 digits in java?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, numbers

I want to format number with commas which are greater than 20 digits in Android. I used `DecimalFormat` class and `TextWatcher` on `EditText` but the problem is when I enter the number greater than 20 digits it shows 0 after 20 digits rather than number.
It works fine till 20 digits.
Any Help should be appreciated.Thanks in Advance

```
private class NumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private DecimalFormat df;
    private DecimalFormat dfnd;
    private boolean hasFractionalPart;

    private EditText et;

    public NumberTextWatcher(EditText et)
    {
        df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###.#####");
        df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
        dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
        this.et = et;
        hasFractionalPart = false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = "NumberTextWatcher";

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        try {
            int inilen, endlen;
            inilen = et.getText().length();

            String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");
            Number n = df.parse(v);
            int cp = et.getSelectionStart();
            if (hasFractionalPart) {
                et.setText(df.format(n));
            } else {
                et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
            }
            endlen = et.getText().length();
             int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
            if (sel > 0 && sel <= et.getText().length()) {

                et.setSelection(sel);
            } else {
                // place cursor at the end?
                et.setSelection(et.getText().length() - 1);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // do nothing?
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // do nothing?
        }

        et.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        if (s.toString().contains(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator())))
        {
            hasFractionalPart = true;
        } else {
            hasFractionalPart = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It would help if you could post your; ideally a compiling+working example that shows the unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Jägermeister Pls check I have edited the question

Comment: Clear point is to tell, what is your input? what is your expected result?

Comment: Side note: **never** go with empty catch-blocks; especially when you are working on some brand new thingy you haven't worked with before; and even more especially ... when you are debugging problems. Probably not related to your problem, but empty catch blocks can be the source of many ugly problems.

Comment: Add few SysOut in the program...You could sort problem yourself

Comment: input is 12345678910111213141516171  output is 123,456,789,101,112,131,4100000

Answer (score 1):

Use `BigDecimal`. [When/why should we use BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320209/javawhy-should-we-use-bigdecimal-instead-of-double-in-the-real-world)

```
    String number = "12345678910111213141516000";
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(number);
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###.#####");
    System.out.println("You want it : " + formatter.format(bd));

    Number num = formatter.parse(number);
    System.out.println("You don't want it : " + formatter.format(num));
```

Output

```
You want it : 12,345,678,910,111,213,141,516,000
You don't want it : 12,345,678,910,111,213,000,000,000
```

Comment: i tried this but it is not working only one comma is placed as i am using textwatcher it places only one comma and rest of number as it is.  Can u pls provide code for that could be used in TextWacther. thanks alot