# Avoid truncate trying to parse string to float in Java Backingbean

Tags: java, string, parsing, backing-beans

I'm trying to parse a string value like this `"2123123.12"` using a portion of code like this

```
String stringAmount = "2123123.12";
float amount = Float.parseFloat(stringAmount);
```

But when I see the value have the next:

```
2123123.0
```

Have any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `float`. It cannot store that many digits of precision ([only 6-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32)). Use `double` for more precision ([15–17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64)), but for values like amounts, you should [use `BigDecimal`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6320209/5221149).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Java`, float can only store 32 `bit` numbers. It stores numbers as 1 `bit` for the sign (-/+), 8 `bits` for the Exponent, and 23 `bits` for the fraction.

Now, looking at your number and printint the decimal part,

`System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(2123123));`

results in 23 `bit` which means `float` does not have enough bits to store the fraction part and hence, it truncates the number.

To store the whole number, you need to use `double` which is 64 `bit` in Java, e.g.:

```
String stringAmount = "2123123.12";
double amount = Double.parseDouble(stringAmount);
System.out.println(amount);
```